# MVC .net Controller not receiving POST data from view

Tags: c#, post, model-view-controller

I'm trying to save data from my view to my Db
but my controller is not receiving the data from the view.

If I inspect the package under the "Network" tab in chrome it is sending the POST with the correct values, but in debugging I can see that the model the controller is receiving is empty

**My Controller:**

```
public class EventController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public EventController()
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(Event walkEvent)
    {
        _context.Event.Add(walkEvent);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

**My view:**

```
@model Doggie.ViewModels.EventViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Save", "Event"))
{
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(e => e.Event.DogOwnerName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.Event.DogOwnerName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Event.DogOwnerName, new {@class = "form-control"})
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(e => e.Event.Location.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.Event.Location.Name)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.Event.LocationId, new SelectList(Model.Location, "Id", "Name"), "Select Location", new {@class = "form-control"})
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(e => e.Event.Date)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.Event.Date)
    @Html.EditorFor(e => e.Event.Date, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control", @placeholder = "dd/mm/yyyy"}})
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(e => e.Event.StartingTime)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.Event.StartingTime)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Event.StartingTime, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder="hh:mm" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(e => e.Event.EstimatedTimeMinutes)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.Event.EstimatedTimeMinutes)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Event.EstimatedTimeMinutes, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder="In minutes" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(e => e.Event.Comment)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.Event.Comment)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(e => e.Event.Comment, new { @class = "form-control"})
</div>

@Html.HiddenFor(e => e.Event.Id)
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

**My EventViewModel:**

```
public class EventViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Location> Location { get; set; }
    public Event Event { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I see your view is missing `@model Event`. Would you confirm that your form view contain `@model Event`

Comment: Please add Model/DTO class definitions. It appears that either the view or the action has the wrong type

Comment: Updated it with my viewmodel @TanvirArjel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `Event` with `EventViewModel` in your `Save` post method parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(EventViewModel walkEvent)
{
    _context.Event.Add(walkEvent.Event); // <-- Here add `Event` from `walkEvent`
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Comment: If I do that it throws this error:
cannot convert from 'Doggie.ViewModels.EventViewModel' to 'Doggie.Models.Event

Comment: Better add your `EventViewModel` code the question.

Comment: Updated it with my viewModel :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insane quickly help :)

Comment: Great to hear that! Welcome.